# iOS Corebluetooth - Bluetooth scanner crashes on start-up

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Edit: Now tested on my actual iphone, and I still get the same crash error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

When I ran the debugger, I ran through the debugger with breakpoints, but it did not reach any other function besides the tLog and the didLoad. The message "Bluetooth LE Device Scanner\r\n\r" went through the tLog a few times without before the app crashed because of the invalid argument

Original -

Info: Mac OSX Yosemite; Xcode 6.4; Using Objective C

Right now, I am following the video tutorial on setting up the bluetooth scanner to detect devices powered by bluetooth.

Video Links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjr8qLE0sxk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjBpB4TcI-U (This part is where crash occurs)

I followed the code and understood the basics of core bluetooth framework. However, when running the test under both the iOS simulator and my iPhone, the application crashes at start-up.

The error I get is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument' (iOS simulator)

I used the breakpoints that involve tlog and start-up, and that same error is still there because it is stuck printing the same thing.

Is there any fix I should do to get the basic bluetooth scanner running?

EDIT - 
The code from the tutorial that I followed:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
// Now we need the properties to do various tasks for the device scanner
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *outputTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *verbositySelector;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *discoveredPeripheral;
@property BOOL bluetoothOn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *valueLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(bool)verboseMode
{
    return (self.verbositySelector.selectedSegmentIndex != 0);
}

-(void)tlog:(NSString*)msg
{
    self.outputTextView.text = [@"\r\n\r\n" stringByAppendingString:self.outputTextView.text];
    self.outputTextView.text = [msg stringByAppendingString:self.outputTextView.text];
}

-(IBAction)startScan:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.bluetoothOn){
        [self tlog:@"Bluetooth is OFF"];
        return;
    }

    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                                options:
     @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @NO}];

}


// Standard template items added in by default. DO NOT REMOVE!


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self tlog:@"Bluetooth LE Device Scanner\r\n\r"];
    self.bluetoothOn = NO;

    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// Core Bluetooth Tasks


-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    [self tlog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Discovered %@, RSSI: %@\n",
                [advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"], RSSI]];
    self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

    if ([self verboseMode]){
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }

}

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
                 error:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{

}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
  didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
  didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
  didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
             error:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        [self tlog:@"Bluetooth OFF"];
        self.bluetoothOn = NO;
    }
    else {
        [self tlog:@"Bluetooth ON"];
        self.bluetoothOn = YES;
    }
}




@end
```

Comment: You should show the actual code in your question rather than a link to a Youtube video.  I can tell you that Core Bluetooth isn't supported on the simulator.  You need to test on a real device.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have addressed the critiques, and I have tested on the device, and I still get the same error of the invalid argument with NSconstantstring with nil argument

There has to be one element that I got to correct to get the program working

Comment: Check that `self.outputTextView` is not nil

Comment: @Paulw11 I have checked it through the breakpoint and the self.outputTextView is always nil, but the msg does have the string. The problem is that I cannot get the outputTextView to store the text

Comment: Check that you have assigned the IBOutlet correctly from your storyboard

Comment: Thank you! I should remember that key technique when making apps: connecting GUI items to actual IBOutlet Objects